# What did Maxwell mean by different types of people to whom science should be presented in different forms?

Tags: quote, maxwell

In my copy of *Physics for Scientists and Engineers with Modern Physics* (Volume 2) by Raymond Serway there is a quote given by James Clerk Maxwell at the start of Part IV.

> For the sake of persons of [...] different types, scientific truth should be presented in different forms, and should be regarded as equally scientific, whether it appears in the robust form and the vivid coloring of a physical illustration, or in the tenuity and paleness of symbolic expression.

Who are these different types of people? Is he categorizing people into visual vs aesthetic vs symbolic thinkers? Or is he saying something else in this context?

Comment: Just wondering, what makes you think there's subtext? It seems like he's saying we should combine math as well as illustrations so that the material can be understood from different views, which appeal to different people. E.g. some books in physics focus heavily on math, others use lots of drawings, others describe things more with words.

Comment: Explain why driving at 120 could use 4 times as much fuel as driving at 60.
Show the formula for wind resistance, "*F = ρCᴰAv²/2*", to some people and they'll immediately see velocity as the most critical factor (since it is squared).
Other people might respond to that with "huh?", but show them a graph of force versus velocity and it will become obvious to them.
Meanwhile the formula-liking people might not appreciate the simple graph and want to know the actual formula to produce it.
In this case it's obviously best to present both views.
It's important to understand one's audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote is from [Maxwell's Address to the Mathematical and Physical Sections](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54151077e4b05407cce436ac/t/546ab4a4e4b0ffb977602da5/1416279204963/Maxwell.pdf) of the British Association for the Advancement of Science at the 40th Meeting in Liverpool (1870). The address offers some quite insightful observations and reflections on study and comprehension in mathematics and sciences, structural analogies in different sciences and their distillation into mathematical forms, and fruitful creative use of "scientific metaphors".

Maxwell does distinguish between abstract/symbolic types, which he considers very rare, and intuitive types (this is roughly associated with left and right hemisphere dominance today). He then further subdivides the intuitive into visual/geometric and physical/motoric types. Here is the full passage:

> "*There  are  men  who,  when  any  relation  or  law,  however  complex,  is  put before them  in  a  symbolical  form,  can  grasp  its  full  meaning  as  a  relation among abstract  quantities.  Such  men  sometimes  treat  with  indifference  the  further statement  that  quantities  actually  exist  in  nature  which  fulfill  this  relation. The mental  image  of   the  concrete  reality  seems  rather  to  disturb  than  to  assist their contemplations.  But  the  great  majority  of   mankind  are  utterly  unable,  without long  training,  to  retain  in  their  minds  the  unembodied  symbols  of   the  pure-mathematician, so that, if  science is ever to become popular, and yet remain scientific, it must be by a profound study and a copious application of  those principles of   the  mathematical  classification  of   quantities  which,  as  we  have seen,  lie  at  the root of  every truly scientific illustration.*

> *There are, as I have said, some minds which can go on contemplating with satisfaction pure quantities presented to the eye by symbols, and to the mind ina form which none but mathematicians can conceive.There are others who feel more enjoyment in following geometrical forms, which they draw on paper, or build up in the  empty  space  before  them. Others,  again,  are  not  content  unless  they  can  project their whole physical energies into the scene which they conjure up. They learn at what a rate the planets rush through space, and they experience a delightful feeling of exhilaration. They calculate the forces with which the heavenly bodies pull at one another, and they feel their own muscles straining with the effort.*

> *To  such  men  momentum,  energy,  mass  are  not  mere  abstract  expressions  of  the results  of   scientific  inquiry.  They  are  words  of   power,  which  stir  their  souls like the  memories  of   childhood. **For  the  sake  of   persons  of   these  different  types, scientific  truth  should  be presented  in  different  forms,  and  should  be  regarded  as equally scientific whether it appears in the robust form and the vivid colouring of  a physical illustration, or in the tenuity and paleness of  a symbolical expression.***"